Kid's new iPhone not showing in FindMy "people" but does show in FindMy "devices", how to fix this?
With the kid's old iPhone, I could see where they were either via the people tab or via the devices tab.
With the new iPhone it only shows in devices which is a bit annoying as it means it doesn't show up in other areas of iOS e.g. iMessage
How can I fix this?
Obviously the device is still under parental control and the location is enabled to be viewable but somehow this link between person and device has been broken.
How can I reestablish this link?

I had what appears to be the same issue with my child's iPhone recently. This is what worked for me:
On my child's iPhone, in Settings > [child's name] > Find My... looked as expected - we saw Find My iPhone: On, and Share My Location was on.
However, there was also some blue clickable text, at Settings > [child's name] > Find My > Use This iPhone as My Location. We tapped that, and Settings > [child's name] > Find My > My Location changed from "[old but similar phone name]" to "This Device".
My child then showed up on my iPhone, in Find My > People.
Note that my child's iPhone is running iOS 15.8 and I believe this problem was introduced for us after we paid Apple for a battery replacement (replacing the whole phone).
